# Is there any alternative to the Delicious feeds?

Tags: json, metadata, feed, bookmarks, delicious-api

Delicious.com has a huge collection of tagged URLs, which it makes public, not least through these RSS/JSON feeds: http://www.delicious.com/help/feeds

Unfortunately the news that Yahoo may discontinue delicious service continues to ping-pong.  So my question:

If we do ever lose these feeds, are there any alternative services which offer similar metadata for URLs?

(For an example application of these feeds, you can try my [Delicious Link Tooltip userscript](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/60831) or the [grab the bookmarklet version from here](http://hwi.ath.cx/code/other/gm_scripts/joeys_userscripts_and_bookmarklets_overview.html).)

Answer (score 3):

Since this question was posted, the Delicious service was bought by new owners, and it still has the compatible webservices and feeds (ref: [Delicious API](http://delicious.com/help/api)).

You could also check the Pinboard service which gained in popularity with the threat of Delicious shutting down. The [Pinboard API](http://pinboard.in/api/) is compatible with the Delicious API, so it's a pretty easy switch to support both.